# Python/Neptune: getting a traversal object

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, gremlin, amazon-neptune

I'm using the `client.Client` class from `gremlin_python.driver` to connect to AWS Neptune. See the following

```
    def _prepare_request(method, url, *, data=None, params=None, headers=None, service='neptune-db'):
        _ = requests.Session()
        request = requests.Request(method=method, url=url, data=data, params=params, headers=headers)

        credentials = Session().get_credentials()
        frozen_creds = credentials.get_frozen_credentials()

        req = AWSRequest(method=method, url=url, data=data, params=params, headers=headers)
        SigV4Auth(frozen_creds, service, os.environ['AWS_REGION']).add_auth(req)
        prepared_iam_req = req.prepare()
        request.headers = dict(prepared_iam_req.headers)
        return request.prepare()

    # https
    http_protocol = 'https'
    uri = f'{http_protocol}://{self.host}:{self.port}/gremlin'
    request = _prepare_request('GET', uri)

    # wss
    ws_url = 'wss://{}:{}/gremlin'.format(self.host, self.port)
    ws_request = httpclient.HTTPRequest(ws_url, headers=dict(request.headers))
    self.conn = client.Client(ws_request, 'g')
```

Now my question how can I used the client.Client object from above to get a traversal object "g".

There is a similar example at https://pypi.org/project/gremlinpython/#description showing this. But I can't use the DriverRemoteConnection in the above code.

```
>>> from gremlin_python.process.anonymous_traversal import traversal
>>> from gremlin_python.driver.driver_remote_connection import DriverRemoteConnection
>>> g = traversal().withRemote(DriverRemoteConnection('ws://localhost:8182/gremlin','g'))
```

Comment: Feels a bit like you're trying to recreate the wheel here.  We already have a Neptune specific implementation of gremlin-python that helps with SigV4 signing here:  https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-neptune-tools/tree/master/neptune-python-utils

Answer (score 1):

Adding an answer in case others find this discussion.

When working with Amazon Neptune using Python, there is a nice open source set of utilities located [here](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-neptune-tools/tree/master/neptune-python-utils) that make it easy to create SigV4 signed requests and perform many other common tasks.

Several of the examples are also useful with any Gremlin Server and not just Neptune.